# Spring5 ResourceHander not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat9

I have a SpringMVC application with Thymeleaf for UI running on Tomcat 9.0.10 server.

Gradle config,

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'io.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0')
    compileOnly('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1')
    compile('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.0')
    compile('javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.1')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.0.7.RELEASE')
    compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:3.0.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.8.RELEASE')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.2.Final')
    compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.2.0')
    testCompile('org.springframework:spring-test:5.0.7.RELEASE')
    testCompile('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.2.0')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.19.1')
}

configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    compile.exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
```

My `AppInitializer` class is

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

And `WebMvcConfig` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "io.example" })
@Log4j2
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        log.info("Does the registry have mapping {}", registry.hasMappingForPattern("/res/**"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("Messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

And `Controller` class is,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/ba")
@Log4j2
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        log.info("HelloController.sayHello() called . . . ");
        model.addAttribute("name", "John");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/login")
    public String loginLoad(Model model) {
        log.info("HelloController.loginLoad() called . . . ");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

And when the page tries to access resources, it get following trace logs,

url -

> http://localhost:8080/res/css/bulma.min.css

logs,

```
21:17:29.704 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3618aa7d
21:17:29.704 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/res/css/bulma.min.css]
21:17:29.704 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@1c8d9b17] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:17:29.704 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /res/css/bulma.min.css
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/res/css/bulma.min.css]
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@473d0890] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/res/css/bulma.min.css]
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@35f4e4ad] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@2c70dd07] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@ba3770a] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/res/css/bulma.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3618aa7d
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/res/css/bulma.min.css]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[2ms]; status=[OK]
21:17:29.706 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/res/css/bulma.min.css]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[2ms]; status=[OK]
```

And I don't see any trace logs for ResourceHander being initialized during startup. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Post your project structure !

Comment: Don't extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` but implement `WebMvcConfigurer` instead. Also you don't need the `ApplicationContextAware` as the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` is `ApplicationContextAware` itself.

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WebMvcConfig` class should be like this as suggested by @M. Deinum

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "io.example" })
@Log4j2
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        log.info("Does the registry have mapping {}", registry.hasMappingForPattern("/res/**"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("Messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. I was following the Thymeleaf reference documents.